# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

Tags: mysql, python

Ошибка:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

Делаю запрос **В** базе:
[image: Запрос в базе]

Делаю запрос **К** базе:

```
val = '7a2e00d09979c3f9f3e3772efd2009'
find_login = "SELECT (login, session_id) FROM users WHERE session_id='{0}' ".format(val)
cursor.execute(find_login)
```

Получаю эту ошибку:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

И за одно по синтаксису. Я знаю что .format(val) нельзя использовать, ибо sqlinjection, но черт побери, я пробовал и так:

```
("...........WHERE session_id = %s"", (val))
```

и так `("...........WHERE session_id = %s"", val)`,

и так `("...........WHERE session_id = (%s)"", (val))`,

и так `("...........WHERE session_id = %s"" % (val))`,

и так `("...........WHERE session_id = ?"", (val))`

И как только не пробовал... все время разные ошибки, то должна быть строка, хотя я и так указываю, что это строка, то `syntax error`  в итоге работает только `format`

P.S. Работаю с модулем MySQLdb

#### UPDATE

всё дело было в скобках... они не нужны тут `(login, session_id)`
а вот по второму вопросу хотелось бы получить ответ